# VMware ESXi slow local storage only on one disk partition

Tags: linux, performance, storage, vmware, esxi

I'm experiencing very odd behaviour of VMware ESXi free hypervisor 6 whilst using local hard drives as a storage for VM's.

Everything works up to one partition.

Here's the setup.

2TB WD RED drive divided onto 2 pieces - one partition 1 TB total in size, and another 500 GB. Both parts/partitions of this drive are assigned to one VM (running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and are formatted and configured in fstab regularly. Everything fine on that.

Now the issue with performance.

When I try to read or write from big (1TB size) partition, mounted in /mnt/bigpart I get expected both write and read speeds (~150 MB/s).
But if try to do the same with smaller partition (500GB), both read and write speeds are 50% lower! So I cannot max read spead above 80 MB/s. Writes are even lower.

I just don't get it. Also esxitop (d) shows exactly the same results. Smaller partition just cannot seem to be any faster.

This is very odd as both partitions are preallocated (in favour of spinning drive speed), and both are physically located on the same hard drive.

I know that in theory with spinning hard drives it can be that end of the drive platter is somewhat slower then the beginning, but this is just too much of a performance hit. 
Additionally, the hard drive has ~360 GB of free space after those preallocations. 
Perhaps I should try to re-assign the smaller partition again but this time with thin provisioning.

Take a look at measurements:

**BIGGER (1TB) PARTITION / DISK**

```
11649792+0 records in
11649792+0 records out
5964693504 bytes (6.0 GB) copied, 39.873 s, 150 MB/s
```

**SMALLER (500GB) PARTITION / DISK**

```
11649792+0 records in
11649792+0 records out
5964693504 bytes (6.0 GB) copied, 67.1635 s, 88.8 MB/s
```

Comment: Info: both pre-allocated partitions are created as zeroedthick (i.e. Thick provisioned lazy zeroed). It is still not clear how the bigger partition outperforms smaller one when they both physically reside on the same hard disk drive, and are created with exactly same options (zeroedthick).

Comment: I'm Eagerly zeroing now smaller partition to test whenever it will help to do a full speed transfers.

Comment: Eagerly zeroing: 100% done.
It took 3h 24m 19s for a 500 GB partition.  Performance gained: nothing. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that in theory with spinning hard drives it can be that end
>   of the drive platter is somewhat slower then the beginning

This is true in practice as well. Look at the sustained transfer rate
of this 2 TB hard drive which is from a different vendor. The chart
displays the sequential read throughput depending on the offset.

In the first terabyte, the sequential read throughput is between 170
and 130 MiB/s, which is pretty close to what you experience (150
MB/s). The throughput drops sharply after the second half of the hard
drive. Even if it does not explain 100% of the performance hit you
experience, it is probably the dominant factor.

[image: Sustained Transfer Rate -- Seagate NAS HDD 2 TB]

Comment: Good comment. Yes, that's why what I have guessed already as you quoted from my 1st post. The odd thing is, after I reformatted entire drive (VMFS) again and took 1.7 TB part and assigned that big part directly to the VM, my speeds are quite different now then in the beginning, my second partition is faster then the first one now.

Comment: And partitioning is done on VM / OS level, so almost entire hard drive (1.7 TB) is presented to the VM which then divides that part into 1 and 0.7 TB partitions. That smaller partition is now faster, while the first one is slower. Crazy :) I will reformat entire VMFS one more time, but this must be problem with disk being slower on one physical platter then on another...

Answer (score 1):

this can (don't have to) be a problem with block alignment.
There is in real-cases no big difference if a vmdk is provisioned as thin or thick.

So you have two local datastores (VMFS5?) on the same harddisk?
Do both Datastores have a block size of 1 MB? (Host -> Configuration -> Storage)
if yes - do both partitions in your guest have a block size of 1 MB too?
is it possible that one partition is with MBR generated and one with GPT? (GPT would be the better way)

Maybe you can do also a SMART check of the HDD - maybe there are some broken sectors.

Comment: Yes, they're on the same HDD. They're both created with defaults from VMware client app. Default block size is 1 MB. On guest, both partitions are created and formatted as ext4 via fdisk, with the same set of commands. Actually they're not partitions on guest, but two separate disks (sdb and sdc) with MBR scheme.  SMART on ESXi is useless completely so I would have to drag the drive to another computer to check it out.

Comment: The thing is, I deleted both VMFS partitions and have re-created both partitons, this time with one big virtual drive presented to the VM. And guess what - after these operations, my entire drive is slow (50% of expected speeds). This is really annoying. Now both my partitons on that VMFS are crawling - in other words entire datastore / disk is slow. I guess we will never wind out why and how the previous partitioning performed such differently.